# Wordpress unknow request slowing down my website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am optimizing a wordpress site using woocommerce plugin.
All seems fine except one unknown request reported by gtmetrix.

It seems that this variable is being appended on every url on my site:

```
?resource=cart
```

This specific request takes 2 to 3 seconds to load 
and here is the response:

```
{"cart":{"token":"","item_count":0,"total_price":0,"items":[]}}
```

Any ideas how to disable this?

Comment: Is the plugin compatible with the version used of Wordpress and Woocommerce?

Comment: This site is using around 30 plugins, and 5 or 7 of those are woocommerce plugins. The site is quiet big thats why I am having hard time doing the disable/enable technique.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect! I advise you to disable all the plugins and reactivate one by one to figure out which to be the error on your site.
30 Plugins are many, and therefore they can try various contrasts between them, between the version of Wordpress and the version of Woocommerce.
After finding the wrong plugin, you can contact the developer to report the bug and have it updated.
Otherwise you will have to delete it and implement the PHP code yourself.